# Age Problem concerning Past and Future

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Robert is $15$ years older than his brother Stan, $s$. However, $y$ years ago, Robert, $r$, was twice as old as Stan. If Stan is now $b$ years old and $b > y$, find the value of 
$b-y$.

The answer is $15$.

I tried the following out:

**Now**: $r = s+15$

**$y$ years ago**: $(r-y) = s(s-y)$

**$b$ years after**: $(r+b) = (s+b)+15$

The $b$'s cancel out no matter what I do. Is my interpretation wrong? How do I arrive at the correct answer? Any hint?

Comment: Your second equation is wrong, it should be $(r-y)=2(s-y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have missed that it's not $b$ years later. It's now. Stan is $b$ years old. So in your notation, $s = b$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $r=s+15$, $r-y=2(s-y)$; then $s+15-y=2s-2y$, and $s=y+15$. If Stan is now $b$ years old, then $b=y+15$ and $b-y=15$.